# msmq message received more than one time in wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, msmq-transaction

I have a wcf service with msmq binding. WCF service process messages receives from MSMQ queue. I am using transactions in client and wcf both. I am having a issue that even after successful processing of the queue message, the message is not deleting from queue and same messages is again received by the wcf service. So one single message is received more then once and processed.

Please help me why the message is coming more then one time even after successful processing. Is there any settings that I need to done at service side?

Comment: Does this happen with every message? Or just some messages?

Comment: Also are you using a database call as part of the message processing>

Comment: Yes its happening with every message.Yes once message receives in wcf I used that message as an identifier to get data from database and after processing again calls the database for updating record.